# Is there a way to know how many columns do we have when using GridCells.Adaptive cells?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to know how many columns do we have when using `GridCells.Adaptive` cells with `LazyVerticalGrid`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way currently is to look at `maxLineSpan` of `LazyGridItemScope`.

```
val columnsCount = 0 

item(span = {
    columnsCount = maxLineSpan
    GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
}) {
                                        
}
```

I don't think it's good enough however since I don't want to assign variables and need it outside this scope. And you shouldn't depend on state in one composable from another composable.